# Android Generate Signed APK getting duplicate issue

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, apk

When I try to generate Signed APK, I am getting the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

The Debug APK is working perfectly. After I include Facebook SDK then only I am facing this issue... Can anyone help me how to solve this issue

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mani.com.howhighru"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

Comment: looks at your libs folder and find any duplicate library

Comment: Your external libraries get same Gson inside. You must find it first.

Comment: Yes I am having gson lib inside the libs folder, I will remove it and try, thanks

Comment: After removing gson lib it worked, thanks for your help